# Monodevelop, where can I download it?

Tags: monodevelop

I was trying to download Monodevelop for mac, but on the official page there is everything but a compiled and downloadable file.
I've read around other threads on different forum and apparently it is required to compile the source code. Is this really the case?

What other alternative may exist for Mac? I just need to dig into some source code, using references and jumping from code portion to others without using the search filter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a binary for Mac, you need to go to Xamarin's homepage and simply download Xamarin Studio.

Xamarin Studio is basically the same thing as MonoDevelop, the only difference is a bit of branding and the inclusion of 3 plugins for their proprietary development offerings, which you can ignore if you're not interested in developing for the mobile platform.